# Filter results in too much data being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I am testing the underscore library.

This is my first example:

```
<!--This is the html code-->
<table id="table" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Ciudad</th><th>Edad</th></tr>
    </thead>
</table>

//This is the javascript code for to load the table
var clienList = [
    {name:'Juan' , city:'Madrid', age:27},
    {name:'Peter', city:'Madrid', age:31},
    {name:'Ana'  , city:'Barcelona', age:28},
    {name:'Oscar', city:'Madrid', age:24},
    {name:'Dani' , city:'Bilbao', age:43},
    {name:'Pedro', city:'Valencia', age:25},
    {name:'Pablo', city:'Sevilla' , age:27},
    {name:'Marta', city:'Sevilla' , age:32}
];
```

I am loading a table using one array of javascript, when i make onclick in the middle cell column (City), i apply the filtering table basing me in the cell content. But the funcionality is not correct, because i dont know update the array.

when applying the filter, for example, "Madrid", add me to the table arrays elements with the  city "Madrid", but i follow seeing all rows, when only should show me the rows with the Madrid city

```
// This is event onclick of the city column table
$("#table-client table tr td.filter-city").click(function() {
    var cell = $(this);
    var filterCity = _.where(clienList, {city: cell.text()});

    //clienList.length = 0;

    //uso de underscore
    _.each(filterCity,function(element) {

    $("#table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+element.name+"</td><td class='filter-city'><a href='#'>"
    +element.city+
    "</a></td><td>"+element.age+"</td></tr></tbody>");
    })       
});
```

Thanks for help me,

Comment: i think you need [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

One thing can be it's `case sensitive`. So if you search for `madrid` it won't show up but only if you search exactly `Madrid` it would show up.

If that is the case you can use `capitalize` mixin given as example in `underscore` page.

```
 _.mixin({
    capitalize: function(string) {
     return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }
});
```

And use it like

```
var filterCity = _.where(clienList, {city: _(cell.val()).capitalize()});
```

Your code ( with a bit of modification)

```js
//This is the javascript code for to load the table
var clienList = [
    {name:'Juan' , city:'Madrid', age:27},
    {name:'Peter', city:'Madrid', age:31},
    {name:'Ana'  , city:'Barcelona', age:28},
    {name:'Oscar', city:'Madrid', age:24},
    {name:'Dani' , city:'Bilbao', age:43},
    {name:'Pedro', city:'Valencia', age:25},
    {name:'Pablo', city:'Sevilla' , age:27},
    {name:'Marta', city:'Sevilla' , age:32}
];
_.mixin({
  capitalize: function(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }
});
// This is event onclick of the city column table
$("#search").click(function() {
    var cell = $('#text');
    var filterCity = _.where(clienList, {city: _(cell.val()).capitalize()});
    console.log(filterCity.length);
    //clienList.length = 0;

    //uso de underscore
     $("#table tbody").empty();
    _.each(filterCity,function(element) {
    $("#table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+element.name+"</td><td class='filter-city'><a href='#'>"
    +element.city+
    "</a></td><td>"+element.age+"</td></tr></tbody>");
    })       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text">
<br>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search">
<br>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Ciudad</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: try click a few times on _search_ button when in textbox for example `Madrid`

Comment: :) :) Corrected again... Guess need some coffee

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you always add filtered result to table, without clearing old.
So you can a bit fix your function for updating table, for example with [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

```js
//This is the javascript code for to load the table
var clienList = [{
  name: 'Juan',
  city: 'Madrid',
  age: 27
}, {
  name: 'Peter',
  city: 'Madrid',
  age: 31
}, {
  name: 'Ana',
  city: 'Barcelona',
  age: 28
}, {
  name: 'Oscar',
  city: 'Madrid',
  age: 24
}, {
  name: 'Dani',
  city: 'Bilbao',
  age: 43
}, {
  name: 'Pedro',
  city: 'Valencia',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: 'Pablo',
  city: 'Sevilla',
  age: 27
}, {
  name: 'Marta',
  city: 'Sevilla',
  age: 32
}];

// This is event onclick of the city column table
$("#table-client table tr td.filter-city").click(function() {
var cell = $(this);
var filterCity = _.where(clienList, {
  city: cell.text()
});

$("#table tbody").replaceWith("<tbody>" +
  filterCity.reduce(function(acc, element) {
    return acc +
      "<tr><td>" + element.name + "</td><td class='filter-city'><a href='#'>" + element.city +
      "</a></td><td>" + element.age + "</td></tr>"
  }, "") +

  "</tbody>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="table-client">
<table >
  <tr>
    <td class="filter-city">Madrid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filter-city">Barcelona</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filter-city">Bilbao</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filter-city">Valencia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filter-city">Sevilla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
<!--This is the html code-->
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Ciudad</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** yet another way just remove all children before adding, like

```js
//This is the javascript code for to load the table
var clienList = [{
  name: 'Juan',
  city: 'Madrid',
  age: 27
}, {
  name: 'Peter',
  city: 'Madrid',
  age: 31
}, {
  name: 'Ana',
  city: 'Barcelona',
  age: 28
}, {
  name: 'Oscar',
  city: 'Madrid',
  age: 24
}, {
  name: 'Dani',
  city: 'Bilbao',
  age: 43
}, {
  name: 'Pedro',
  city: 'Valencia',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: 'Pablo',
  city: 'Sevilla',
  age: 27
}, {
  name: 'Marta',
  city: 'Sevilla',
  age: 32
}];

// This is event onclick of the city column table
$("#table-client table tr td.filter-city").click(function() {
  var cell = $(this);
  var filterCity = _.where(clienList, {
    city: cell.text()
  });

  $("#table tbody").empty();
  //uso de underscore
  _.each(filterCity, function(element) {

    $("#table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + element.name + "</td><td class='filter-city'><a href='#'>" + element.city +
      "</a></td><td>" + element.age + "</td></tr>");
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="table-client">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter-city">Madrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter-city">Barcelona</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter-city">Bilbao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter-city">Valencia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filter-city">Sevilla</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!--This is the html code-->
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Ciudad</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```